# categorical_crossentropy returns small loss value even if accuracy is 1.00 in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, cross-entropy

I have a LSTM model which is designed for multi-classification problem. When training, the accuracy is acutally 1.00. But still returns small loss value. What does it mean? All targets are predicted correctly. Why can not the loss value be zero?

```
adadelta = Adadelta(clipnorm=1.)
model.compile(optimizer=adadelta,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              sample_weight_mode='temporal',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The loss value is like below.

```
Epoch 12/12
1000/1000 [==============================] - 38s - loss: 1.2053e-04 - acc: 1.0000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The network is optimizing the loss. The loss is in your case the categorical crossentropy. The categorical measures a logarithmic values of the probability of being right.

It goes like this for one sample `y_pred` predicted by your network with `y_true` being the true target value : `y_true` is binary because you want to predict if it belongs to a certain class or not and `y_pred` is a float number between 0 and 1 that you can interpret as the probability  of belonging to the class.

The formula for one sample is :

```
loss_sample = y_true * ln(y_pred) + (1-y_true) * ln(1-y_pred)
```

so if `y_true` is 1 (the sample belongs to that class), then `loss_sample = ln(y_pred)` and if `y_true` is 0 ,  then `loss_sample = ln(1-y_pred)`. This makes sense because if `y_true` is 1, you want your loss to be as small as possible, so you want `y_pred` to be 1. If `y_true` is 0, your loss will decrease if `1-y_pred` is close to 1, so if y_pred is 0.

As for the accuracy, it's will be equal to 1 if all the samples have a probability of belonging to the right class being above the 0.5 threshold.

This means that if you have a training set with 3 samples and targets `y1 = 1`, `y2 = 0`, `y3 = 1` and you predict `y1_hat = 0.6`, `y2_hat = 0.2`, `y3_hat = 0.9`. Then your accuracy will be 100% but your loss will be `loss = ln(0.6) + ln(1-0.2) + ln(0.9)` which is non zero.

**To summarize** : you predict probabilities of belonging to a certain class, the loss computes the confidence of being right, and the accuracy just cuts a decision based on the prediction without taking into account the confidence.

You can have a perfect accuracy score because your networks takes the right decisions but a positive loss because your network isn't prefectly confident about the results.

Is that clearer ?